# How to create Ionic2 custom build process?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

As a school project I am making a multi-platform app. I decided to use JavaScript. I thought it would be great to have something like an MVVM pattern with Ionic2 where VM is the Angular2 part of Ionic and I would have two Views. One for mobile(the html/css parts of Ionic), and Electron for desktop. I have a problem though. In a basic Ionic project the View and the Angular part is tightly coupled, I mean they are in the same directory, cannot change the HTMLs easily.

What I thought would be great (although other solutions are welcome) is to have an "ionic" folder and a "desktop" folder, both the same structure same file names. 
When building the app for mobile with Ionic I want all the files in the src folder to be copied to a dist/ folder and html,css files from src/ionic copied to their place like in a normal ionic project(the only difference, that it would be under a dist/ folder not src/, so I have to make the www/index.html to include these too instead of src/ which it does normally in ).
And when building for Desktop I just copy all the things the same way but from src/desktop instead of src/ionic.

That way I could have my business logic in "plain" Angular2 and could be reused creating the app both for desktop and mobile.

So my question is can I modify the Ionic build process somehow, to allow me to do this? Can I create my own gulp or grunt file? Or webpack? How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I wrote my own gulp file, to copy the files to src/.tmp/ and after the copy task is ready I call the original scripts which are used by ionic to serve, build the projects. I could solve everything with this method.

On serve task gulp watches for changes in src/ files excluding src/.tmp and copies the changed files to the src/.tmp folder. Which is watched by ionic and rebuilt everytime something changes.

I was lucky because ionic is built on top of angular, so the builder toolset used by ionic is 100% compatible with plain angular projects.